# How can I add PostgreSQL support in PHP bundled in XAMPP?

Tags: php, windows, apache, postgresql, xampp

Apache: v.2.2.14 
PHP: 5.3.1 
PostgreSQL: 8.4 
XAMPP: version 1.7.3

Comment: **Looks like you should ask this on http://www.serverfault.com/ .**

Comment: oh I'm sorry. I didn't realize that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

XAMPP ships with a php_pgsql.dll/so, i.e. all you have to do is to edit the php.ini and remove the semicolon before

```
extension = php_pgsql.dll
```

and then restart the apache.

Comment: Googlers, this is also the answer to the —deeply misleading— phpPgAdmin error message: `your PHP installation does not support PostgreSQL. You need to recompile PHP using the --with-pgsql configure option.`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, check https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pgsql.php